# how to commafy numbers in jinja?

Tags: jinja2

I was wondering about how to commafy large digits in jinja so that instead of [$10000 / $100000 / $1000000] these numbers would be displayed as such [$10,000 / $100,000 / $1,000,000]

I've been looking all over but surprisingly couldn't find a quick simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best method is to use Python's `locale` module.  Register a jinja filter that will return a formatted value.  E.g:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> import locale
```

Set an appropriate locale (this controls the currency symbol, grouping behavior, etc):

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
'en_US'
```

Define a currency filter function:

```
>>> def currency(val):
...     return locale.currency(val, grouping=True)
...
```

Register the filter function as a filter in your Jinja environment:

```
>>> env = jinja2.Environment()
>>> env.filters['currency'] =  currency
```

Now we can create a template that uses the new `currency` filter:

```
>>> template = env.from_string('{{ val|currency }}')
>>> print(template.render(val=1000000))
$1,000,000.00
>>> print(template.render(val=100000))
$100,000.00
```

---

If you don't care about the locale (e.g., you know you're always going to be dealing with US Dollars, for example), you can just use string `format` method:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> template = jinja2.Template('{{ "${:,.2f}".format(val) }}')
>>> print(template.render(val=1000000))
$1,000,000.00
>>> print(template.render(val=100000))
$100,000.00
```

See [the format specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec) in the python docs for information about how that format string works.